# htaccess mobile redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mobile

I have a desktop and mobile site - I have the following in my htaccess file which means on a mobile site it gets stuck in a loop trying to redirect back to the main root of the domain and back to the mobile site folder on the domain.

How can I stop this happening?

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.co.uk$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) /404.php [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 20000 seconds"
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /domain-news/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /domain-news/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^file=(.+)$
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.aspx$ $1.php?f=%1

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    # Check if this is the noredirect query string
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)
    # Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
    RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.domain.co.uk]

    # Check if this looks like a mobile device
    # (You could add another [OR] to the second one and add in what you
    #  had to check, but I believe most mobile devices should send at
    #  least one of these headers)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}"acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

    # Check if we're not already on the mobile site
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
    # Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 

    # Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

    # Now redirect to the mobile site
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.co.uk/m [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way but i took out the look ups for if the site is a mobile and put

```
#mobile redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera|mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /m/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which has worked nicely.